# Element of list get selected slowly

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i made this list of elements.
when element is pressed, it's added to the state array.

in the list render, i check if element is in state array to change the background color.

it's working but , the user experience is bad, it's slow.

how can i optimise this component ?

thanks by advance

```
export default function ListStyleSpectacle({ navigation}) {

 

const data = [
  { key:0, value: "Art du récit"},
  { key:1,value: "Atelier"},
  { key:2, value: "Boulevard"},
  { key:3,value: "Café-théâtre"},
 
  

];

const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(StoreContext);



const addStylesRecherches = (item) => {

 
   dispatch({
    type: "ADD_STYLES_RECHERCHES",
    payload: item,
  });


};


const removeStylesRecherches = (item) => {


dispatch({
  type: "DELETE_STYLES_RECHERCHES",
  payload: item,
});

 
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(state.StylesRecherches);
 

}, [state.StylesRecherches]);



return (
  <AlphabetList
    data={data}
    indexLetterStyle={{ 
      color: 'blue', 
      fontSize: 15,
    }}
    renderCustomItem={(item) => (

      <View
      key={item.key} 
      >
      <Pressable 
       
          onPress={()  =>
            {
              if(state.StylesRecherches.includes(item.value)){
                removeStylesRecherches(item);
              }else{
                addStylesRecherches(item);
              }
              //console.log(styles_list);
            }
          }
>
      <View 
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 10, 
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
        backgroundColor: state.StylesRecherches.includes(item.value) ? '#00cc00' : '#f2f2f2' 
      }}
      
    
      
      >
        
        <Text style={styles.listItemLabel}>{item.value}</Text>
       
      </View>
      </Pressable>
      </View>

    )}
    renderCustomSectionHeader={(section) => (
      <View style={styles.sectionHeaderContainer} key={section.key}>
        <Text style={styles.sectionHeaderLabel}>{section.title}</Text>
      </View>
    )}
  />
)


}
```

the part of the reducer :

```
case "ADD_STYLES_RECHERCHES":
     
      return {
        ...state,
        
        StylesRecherches: [...state.StylesRecherches, action.payload.value],
      };
      
      case "DELETE_STYLES_RECHERCHES" : 
      
        
        var array = [...state.StylesRecherches]; // make a separate copy of the array
        var index = array.indexOf(action.payload.value)
        if (index !== -1) {
          array.splice(index, 1);
          
        }

        return {
          ...state,
          StylesRecherches: array
        };
```

Comment: Use state instead of dispatching to props. and using state also take little bit time. but its far better than props

Comment: hello mano, i need to keep using state, because, the elements are used in other component, do you think my double condition in render is making things slow ? in console, state is not long to be updated, thanks

Comment: i dont think so, however using reducers will make thins little bit slow.. you can process things in state and then pass it to reducers(once you done)

Comment: @Manojkanth I'm sorry, but that isn't true.  Reducers do not increase load in any realistic way.

Comment: just for information, it's allready use a reducer with dispatches in my store component

Comment: @Abe sorry. while working with these, i felt state is faster than reducers while processing big array. may be im wrong. btw thanks for that comment.

Comment: @Manojkanth no problem! Reducers are just ordinary functions, they incur no real cost on their own. Using an object vs an array can be a massive difference in state or reducers though.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're iterating through the array, potentially the entire array, every time you need to select or deselect one item.  Your items already have unique IDs or keys; store the selected state as an object with ID keys instead of an array.

You don't show your reducer, but I assume it's something like this:

```js
const initialState = [];

...
    addStylesRecherches(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    removeStylesRecherches(state, action) {
      state.filter(item => item.key !== action.payload.key);
    },
```

Instead, make your state an object, and turn IDs on and off

```js
const initialState = {};

...
    addStylesRecherches(state, action) {
      state[action.payload.key] = true;
    },
    removeStylesRecherches(state, action) {
      state[action.payload.key] = false;
    },
```

Then you can rewrite your onPress function to match:

```js
  onPress={() => {
    if (state.StylesRecherches[item.key]) {
      removeStylesRecherches(item);
    } else {
      addStylesRecherches(item);
    }
  }}
```

This makes gives your operation an O(1) cost instead of O(n), where n is the size of your list.  [Here's one blog](https://medium.com/@manrvaldez.92/analyzing-performance-of-arrays-and-objects-with-big-o-notation-260cef5c7e6) that does a pretty good job of explaining the difference.

If your data size is really 4, this will have a barely noticeable impact, but as you go into the hundreds and thousands of items the difference will be pretty clear.

Comment: Thanks, you right, my reducer ( that i added to the post) looks like yours. i need to keep my state array, but thanks for the idea, it give some idea to test

Comment: i did it with a new action SELECT_STYLES_RECHERCHES, it faster but still not reactive, thanks anyway

Comment: thanks, i finally create a new context and the dispatching is not slow as before

Comment: but i keep doing 2 dispatch 1 for background color the other to fill the array. the dispatch by key is more faster , now, i click and the color change without lag, thanks a lot

Comment: Glad it helped, I'm not sure I understand your ultimate solution!  If what worked for you is different enough from my answer, feel free to make another answer and mark it as accepted.